# call parent method using parent properties

Tags: c#

I want to create a sort function.

```
public class Program 
{
    public static void Main() 
    {
        // the error is here
        Child1.SortList(new List<Child1>() {});
    }
}

public class Parent
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Order { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateBegin { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> DateEnd { get; set; }

    public static List<Parent> SortList(List<Parent> list)
    {
        return list
            .Where(x => 
                   DateTime.Compare(x.DateBegin, DateTime.Today) <= 0 && 
                   (
                       x.DateEnd == null || 
                       DateTime.Compare((DateTime)x.DateEnd, DateTime.Today) > 0))
            .OrderBy(x => x.Order)
            .ToList();
    }
}

public class Child1 : Parent
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

When I call `SortList()`, I got an error cannot convert `Child1` to `Parent`.
 I don't know how to implement the interface or T?

Comment: Please provide a complete example of how you're calling it and the *exact* error message. (Also, if you could fix the formatting a bit, that would be much appreciated. It's quite hard to read at the moment.)

Comment: `Child1 : Parent` please don't do this. unless the names aren't what I think they are

Comment: @Steve I don't see any problem with the naming, in the inheritance tree, `Child1` is considered a "child" of the `Parent` class. Likewise, `Parent` is the "super" class of any of its children.

Comment: The error message isn't the same as you're saying. It's `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Child1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Parent>'` - there's a huge difference between there not being a conversion from `Child1` to `Parent` and there not being a conversion from `List<Child1>` to `List<Parent>`. This is why it's important to always provide the *exact* error message, copied and pasted rather than just summarized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# Lists are not [covariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/). You can use `IEnumerable` instead, which is covariant.

```
List<string> strings = new List<string>();

IEnumerable<object> objects = strings; // this does work
List<object> objectList = strings; // this does not work
```

Here is a simplified version of what will work for you.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Child1.SortList(new List<Child1>() {});
    }
}

public class Parent
{
    public static List<Parent> SortList(IEnumerable<Parent> list)
    {
        // et cetera
    }
}

public class Child1 : Parent { }
```